# menu desplegable y responsive bootstrap

Tags: html5, bootstrap, navbar

Estoy haciendo una web con bootstrap y tengo un problema. Necesito un id para hacer el menú desplegable y un id para que que cuando sea en pantallas pequeñas el menú se esconda y en un botón se despliegue.

El problema es que es poner un id o otro y quiero los dos, gracias de antemano y adjunto el código del `header`, los dos id que necesito están puestos donde los necesito. Un id es para el menú desplegable y el otro es para que cuando la pantalla sea pequeña el menú se esconda y el otro se muestra cuando se aprieta un botón:

```
<html>
<header>
<div class="container-fluid menu fixed-top">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top menu container align-middle letra-menu">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href=""><img src="http://www.pp.es/sites/all/themes/partidopopular/images/logotipo.png"
            alt="Página de inicio"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse"
          aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse menu" id="navbarNavDropdown navbarCollapse">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle active" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="inline text-white">Conócenos</span><span
                  class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu color-azul desplegable" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a class="dropdown-item text-white " href="#">Bienvenida</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="#">Quién es quién</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="#">Transparencia</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="#">Sedes</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="#">En el exterior</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="#">In Memoriam</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu color-azul desplegable" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a class="dropdown-item text-white " href="#">Historia</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="#">Programas</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="#">Elecciones</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="#">Nuevas Generaciones</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="#">Internacional</a>

                    </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class=" text-white nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                      Temas
                    </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu color-azul desplegable" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="dropdown-item text-white " href="#">Justicia</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="#">Familia</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="#">Transparencia y Regeneración</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="#">Economía</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="#">Mujer e igualdad</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="#">Más temas</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class=" text-white nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                      Actualidad
                    </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu color-azul desplegable" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="dropdown-item text-white " href="#">Destacados</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="#">Noticias</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="#">Videos</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="#">Imágenes</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="#">Documentos</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="#">Agenda</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="#">Argumentos populares</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class=" text-white nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                      Participa
                    </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu color-azul desplegable" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="dropdown-item text-white " href="#">Cómo colaborar</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="#">En Internet</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="#">Suscríbete</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="#">Donaciones</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="#">Únete</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="inline text-white">Formulario</span></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2 search" style="text-align: right; margin-top: 20px; margin-right: 13px;"
              type="text" placeholder="" aria-label="Search">
          </form>
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item post-search">
              <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Contacta</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item post-search">
              <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Afíliate</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El menú colapsable ya lo trae `Bootstrap` con el `id="collapsibleNavbar"` y los items desplegables los puedes manejar con la `class="dropdown-menu"`. Lo indispensable es importar todas las dependencias entre las etiquetas `<head>`...`</head>`.

Te dejo este ejemplo con `Bootstrap 4` tomando algunas opciones de tu menú. *Ejecuta el `snippet` en pantalla completa para que puedas visualizar el comportamiento del `navbar` al cambiar el tamaño de la pantalla.*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Menú desplegable y colapsable</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/60/30"
            alt="Página de inicio"></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Conócenos<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Bienvenida</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Quién es quién</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Transparencia</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sedes</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">En el exterior</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">In Memoriam</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Temas<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Justicia</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Familia</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Transparencia y Regeneración</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Economía</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Mujer e igualdad</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Más temas</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Actualidad<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Destacados</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Noticias</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Imágenes</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Documentos</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Agenda</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Argumentos populares</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Participa<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Cómo colaborar</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">En Internet</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Suscríbete</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Donaciones</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Únete</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>  
    </ul>
  </div>  
</nav>
<br>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Aquí va el contenido</h3>
  <p>En esta zona va el contenido de tu pagina</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```